# Apache TomEE: want to user Mojarra JSF in my project instead of built-in Apache MyFaces

Tags: jsf, myfaces, mojarra

I have a related question. I am migrating my project from Jboss to TomEE. I was using Mojarra JSF, and have been having problems trying to get everything working using MyFaces (view Encryption problems, UI problems, ajax problems, etc). I just want to include Mojarra jars in my project, but looks like they are clashing with the built-in MyFaces jars that comes bundled with TomEE. I keep getting UnSupported exceptions.

Is there a way to specify that the Mojarra JSF should override myfaces? Is there a web.xml parameter or something? By the way, I am not using Maven (I've seen many examples with pom.xml dependency tags that cannot help me).

Comment: Can you specify which versions (mojarra, myfaces, tomcat, Jboss) you are using? Technically, you should not be able to use both implementations together, you have to choose either Mojarra or MyFaces

Answer (score 1):

I tried that for 3 days, after making many tweaks(error stack-> google ->change some exotic xml parameter-> new error stack->google->change some exotic xml parameter etc....), I could make it work, except that EJB injection was not working anymore (getting null). So I surrendered and use myfaces instead of mojarra.